# Wie den eigenen Namen am Anfang einer E-Mail erwähnen?

Tags: letter, idiomaticity

Da es mir unumgänglich schien, am Anfang einer E-Mail meinen Namen zu erwähnen, suchte ich nach einer Alternative zum üblichen »mein Name ist«. Es fiel mir folgende Formulierung ein:

> Sehr geehrte Frau X,
>
> Ihnen schreibt Y ...

Oder:

> es schreibt Ihnen Y ...

Als Nichtmuttersprachlerin kann ich jedoch nicht einschätzen, ob diese Formulierung (un)natürlich klingt. Wie würde ein Muttersprachler dies empfinden?

Comment: Also ich schreibe meinen Namen immer am Schluss der Email.

Comment: Denk auch dran, Dein Email-Program vernünftig einzustellen, so dass Dein Name als Abesnder direkt im Header der Email und somit in der Übersicht des Posteingangs steht. Schreib da nicht so einen Käse rein wie "Yahoo", weil es Dein Yahoo-Account ist. Beim Empfänger sieht das leicht so aus, als würdest u behaupten, Yahoo zu sein.

Comment: Danke Robert. Ich habe jedoch einen Account bei gmail; da gibt es kein solches Problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im Wesentlichen stimme ich dem Kommentar von 5pike zu. Sowohl in einem Brief als auch in einer E-Mail befindet sich mein Name am Schluss

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>   Em1

In einem Brief ist der Name auch im Briefkopf vorgesehen.
Im Falle einer E-Mail befindet sich mein Name auch i. d. R. im Absenderfeld, sofern meine E-Mail-Adresse meinen Namen beinhaltet.

Also normalerweise sollte eine solche Einleitung schon fast überflüssig sein. Ich habe noch just gestern eine E-Mail geschrieben, wo ich eingangs einige Worte über mich selbst verloren habe; meinen Namen habe ich aber nicht explizit erwähnt, sondern nur die für den Anlass meiner Mail wichtigen Eckdaten und warum ich nun schreibe.

Trotzdem kann es natürlich Situationen geben, in denen man sich am Anfang kurz vorstellen möchte.
Mir persönlich gefallen beide von dir vorgeschlagenen Varianten nicht. Wenn ich nun meinen Namen schreiben wollte, würde ich schlicht "Ich heiße …" schreiben.

Falls es dir zu abrupt erscheint, eine E-Mail oder ein Brief mit diesen Worten zu starten, könnte man (eine eigentliche unnötige) Einleitung in der Form "Ich möchte mich kurz vorstellen: Ich heiße …" anbringen.

**To cut a long story short:**
Ich würde hinterfragen, ob es notwendig ist, seinen Namen nochmals explizit zu erwähnen und falls ja, dann einfach "Ich heiße …". Wichtiger sind aber Eckdaten, die den Anlass der E-Mail beschreiben, als dein Name, der am Ende der Mail / des Briefes sowieso erscheint.

Comment: Danke. Ich stimme sowohl Dir als auch 5pike zu. Einen äußerst gewichtigen Grund dazu, meinen Namen am Anfang zu schreiben, konnte ich nach einer zweiten Überlegung nicht mehr finden. Dein Kommentar bezüglich der konkreten Formulierung ist mir auch sehr hilfreich.

Answer (score 0):

Ich gehe davon aus, dass du einen Grund hast, um die E-Mail so anzufangen. Dann wähle lieber die Variante ohne *es*. Beide sind korrekt, die erste klingt stilistisch aber besser.